# Convert Data table to nested json - webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have to join two tables and pass it's values in json format.
I have done like below

```
    public DataTable LoadDetails()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string sql = "SELECT table_header.userid,table_header.name,table_details.Question_no,table_details.Question from table_header INNER JOIN table_details ON table_header.userid =table_details.useridWHERE table_header.active=@active";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", 1);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = null;

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                dt.Rows.Add("fail");
            }

            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception show_error)
        {
            throw show_error;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And in web api controller

```
 [Route("LoadDetails"), HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoadDetails()
    {
        try
        {
            var Response = objLogic.LoadDetails();
            var Result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Response, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            return Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpError Error = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "IsSuccess", false } };
            return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Error);
        }
    }
```

Now I got the response as below,

```
[{"userid":42,"name":"Saran","Question_no":1,"Question":"xxxx?"},{"userid":42,"name":"Saran","Question_no":2,"Question":"yyyyy?"},{"userid":42,"name":"Saran","Question_no":3,"Question":"zzzz?"}]
```

Since these userid and name are common for all rows, how can I make it common in json string?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Normalized` JSON.

Step 1 - Create a model which suits your requirement of Normalized json

```
public class Normalized
{
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<NormalizedQuestion> questions { get; set; }
}

public class NormalizedQuestion
{
    public int Question_no { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2 - Loop through denormalized data and convert to JSON

```
var normalized = new Normalized();
var normalizedQuestions = new List<NormalizedQuestion>();
foreach (var record in deNormalizedData)
{
    normalized.userid = record.userid;
    normalized.name = record.name;
    normalizedQuestions.Add(new NormalizedQuestion() { Question = record.Question, Question_no = record.Question_no });                    
}
normalized.questions = normalizedQuestions;
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(normalized));
```

Here is the Output

```
{
    "userid": 42,
    "name": "Saran",
    "questions": [
        {
            "Question_no": 1,
            "Question": "xxxx?"
        },
        {
            "Question_no": 2,
            "Question": "yyyyy?"
        },
        {
            "Question_no": 3,
            "Question": "zzzz?"
        }
    ]
}
```